# Unity cannot compile C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I am writing a simple movement script and Unity keeps giving compiler errors. It gives stupid errors like error because '=' or ';' exists.

The exact error for example is: Assets\Move.cs(7,11): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    speed = 5;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: `speed` isn't declared anywhere, and assignment outside a function is not allowed unless it is done with the declaration. In short, your code is not valid but the error is.

Comment: You have to specify the type, e.g. `int speed = 5;`

Comment: "it gives stupid errors" i know im not supposed to comment something as trival as this, but i lol'd :D anyway, to add something productive, the compiler does not know what data-type `speed` is supposed to be. if you declare a variable, you need to give it a type (int, float, string, object, ...) in your case float would make the most sense.

Comment: Lol I actually figured out what it was like 10 minutes after I posted this and decided to keep this up to make sure I am roasted for this mess. You guys are too nice. Can't believe I wasted like 3 hours on this! Stupid af

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a data type before the variable. You'll need to change it to this:

```
int speed = 5;
```

[Here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-data-types) is all the basic C# data types, and there's a bunch of unity data types (I couldn't find an official list).

Comment: lol good luck making a list of all Unity data types ;) [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/)